# Unity3D - How Can I parse nested duplicate Json

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

1. how to parse json via unity3d with duplicate json ,. this is the code that i have ..

> ```
> [System.Serializable]
>     public class datagame
>     {
>         public string num_id;
>         public string delay;
>         public string status;
>         public string trac;
>         public string num_id;
>       public dataIn[] data;
>   }
>   [System.Serializable]
>   public struct dataIn
>     {
>         public string ID;
>         public string Sort;
>         public string UnitID;
>     }
>
>   datagame dataz;
> ```

and this is the json i have.

```
{
  "result": "ok",
  "num_id": "19",
  "active": "1",
  "datagame": {
    "id": "3",
    "delay": "1200",
    "status": "0",
    "trac": "NA",
    "num_id": "19",
    "data": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"PowerBtn Spiral\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"Effect Spiral\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"Zdata numQ\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\",\r\n    \"UnitID\":\"c17\"\r\n  }\r\n]"
  }
}
```

2. how can i to remove \r\n and \ in the json with c# code in unity3d

Answer (score 3):

You mean like e.g.

```
// This is how your top level Json actually looks like
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public string result;
    public string num_id;
    public string active;
    public Datagame datagame;
}

[Serializable]
public class Datagame
{
    public string num_id;
    public string delay;
    public string status;
    public string trac;
    public string num_id;

    // At this level your data is still simply a string
    public string data;
}

// This will be the root for this inner json array
[Serializable]
public class DataArray
{
    public dataIn[] values;
}

[Serializable]
public class dataIn
{
    public string ID;
    public string Sort;
    public string UnitID;
}
```

And then double parse the json like e.g.

```
// Get the outer class
var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);
// Get the game data instance
var datagame = root.datagame;
// Wrap this inner json array to fit the DataArray structure
var innerJson = "{\"values\":" + datagame.data + "}";
// Now parse this inner json to DataArray
var dataArray = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataArray>(innerJson);
// Finally you have your data items
dataIn[] dataIns = dataArray.values;
```

Comment: yes like that, but the error here.

var innerJson = "{/"values/":" + datagame.data + "}";

this log
error CS1002: ; expected

Comment: @H-ndiSantoso this is caused because it should be backslash (\) instead of slash(/) to skip the quotes (probably derHugo is quickly typing this on his phone and just missed). Try with var innerJson = "{\"values\":" + datagame.data + "}"; ^^

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your first point but for the second one try something like:

```
string dataString = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"PowerBtn Spiral\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"Effect Spiral\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\":\"Zdata numQ\",\r\n    \"Sort\":\"1\",\r\n    \"UnitID\":\"c17\"\r\n  }\r\n]";

string data = Regex.Replace(dataString , @"\\r\\n", "");
string finaldata = Regex.Replace(data, @"\\""", "");
```